# End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed thrown Sending Large Images over UDP Socket

Tags: c#, image, exception, udp, deserialization

I am Sending **Jpeg Encoded** Images as Serialized Complex object over **UDP Socket**..As UDP Datagram Support max. Length of **52KB to 54KB**,I m Writing the arrived Datagrams to memory stream that I could DeSerialize it at once.

Receiver End Code:

```
while (AccumulatingBytes <= TotalSizeOfComplexObject)//Size of Complex Object after Serialization which I get through TCP//
{
    byte[] Recievedbytes = UdpListener.Receive(ref RemoteEndPoint);//I m Sending fixed size of 204 NUMBER OF BYTES

    ImageStream = new MemoryStream();
    ImageStream.Position = (long)AccumulatingBytes;
    ImageStream.Write(Recievedbytes, 0, Recievedbytes.Length);

    AccumulatingBytes += 204;
}
```

When I deSerialize this `Memory Stream Exception` is Thrown.

Comment: If you deserialize the stream without sending it over the network does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some obvious observations that may help...

- why a new `MemoryStream` each time in the loop? this is the most immediate problem
- why not `AccumulatingBytes += Receivedbytes.Length;`

Also; if you aren't handling errors and missing data yourself, use TCP.

So something like:

```
ImageStream = new MemoryStream();
while (AccumulatingBytes <= TotalSizeOfComplexObject)
{
    byte[] Recievedbytes = UdpListener.Receive(ref RemoteEndPoint);

    ImageStream.Write(Recievedbytes, 0, Recievedbytes.Length);

    AccumulatingBytes += Recievedbytes.Length;
}
```

then set `ImageStream.Position = 0` before deserializing. You should also probably check that `UdpListener` isn't reporting EOFs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write bytes stream at 0 place all the time?

```
ImageStream.Write(Recievedbytes, 0, Recievedbytes.Length);
```

Maybe you need instead of zero place variable AccumulatingBytes ?

Comment: No, that is writing `Recievedbytes` from the 1st (zeroth) byte of the array; it doesn't impact where it is written to.

Comment: Exactly.Every Time the Receiviedbytes array populated with new data.